# MySQL Upgrade RPM

Tags: mysql, rpm, tar, mysql5

I have a centos5.5 system and have MySQL 5.0.27 install. Now I want to upgrade this to MySQL 5.5.28(Latest). I have two questions,

1. What is the difference between RPM(Redhat) which is recommended and Generic binary tarball. Do they have performance difference, i.e. will the Specific RPM build perform better than generic tarball?
2. What is the process of RPM upgrade of the same.

Answer (score 2):

Beware that the RPMs distributed by MySQL themselves are not binary compatible with your system and will break compatibility with other existing software, as well as breaking the dependency chain that yum maintains. (MySQL intends to fix its RPM packages in [version 5.7](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-2.html).)

For people needing an updated version of MySQL, I generally recommend using the [remi repository](http://rpms.remirepo.net/), since he provides packages with maximum backward compatibility that will not break yum (or other things!).

Comment: I'm seeing this question now after 'community' made it pop up. The oracle-provided RPM's are OK to use again these days.

Answer (score 0):

1 . The RedHat RPM has been built specifically for RedHat OS. That should mean that general dependencies and features are ensured to work on that system. It will be built for a specific range of RedHat releases and/or kernel versions.

Also installing via RPM will (hopefully) give a sane and clear error if a dependency is not found so you can easily go and install it.

The tarball is, as you say, a generic binary build. In most circumstances it should work but won't be specifically built for RedHat and any OS-specific file paths or constraints.

2 . RPM upgrade process:

rpm -Uvh rpmname.rpm

U is upgrade, v is verbose so you get details, h is print a hash as it installs (looks nicer)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest sticking with the version in the stock yum repository unless you have a compelling feature-based reason to upgrade.   RHEL/CentOS backports security fixes from upstream versions into their packages so they remain secure.